# Is there a way to find number of elements in kotlin channel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-coroutine-channel

I am using a Channel because I needed a non-blocking queue. I also want to maintain certain number of elements in the queue by prefetching (to avoid fetch-after-going-empty) so that there are elements always present when needed.

To trigger prefetching, I need to know if the size has fallen below a threshold. However, I do not see any .size() method on Kotlin Channel or ReceiveChannel. There is an experiment api .isEmpty() though.

Is expecting size() here is anti-pattern?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but why do you need to manually maintain the current queue size and fetching mechanism? If you create a channel of size N and the producer will always fetch and send in a loop, then it will always try to keep N elements in the queue, ready to be consumed.

Comment: @broot queue is fed by response from SDK/network which may be expensive. So unless queue is running low, do not want to trigger the external fetch.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Ok, maybe another question: if items are fetched on demand then how could it ever happen the queue contains more items than the prefetch threshold? Do you have another mechanism that feeds the queue?

Comment: Say queue size is 10, low watermark/threshold is 5. Initially prefetch 10. Consume on demand. When queue size reaches 5, do another fetch 5, now size will be back to 10.

Comment: Yeah, so wouldn't it work exactly as you said if you create a channel of size 5 and then simply do something like: `while (true) { fetchItems(5).forEach { channel.send(it) } }`? No observing the size, no manual refetching, just simple producer-consumer pattern. You might want to add the initial fetch to get 10 items instead of 5.

Comment: Anyway, I'm surprised channel doesn't provide its current size. Of course, you can just use atomic integer and increment/decrement in at the producer/consumer side, but still, I don't see a good reason to not have this in the first place.